# c++ float array dimensions

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, unix

I am trying to adapt some functional Unix c++ to a Windows environment.

In the original code, there is:

```
float *drowPtrs[_imageRows];
```

To move this to windows, I have adjusted it to:

```
float *drowPtrs = new float[_imageRows];
```

However, later in the function, there is this line:

```
 float &otherDistance = drowPtrs[y][x];
```

Obviously I have just initialized `drowPtrs` as a one dimensional array, so this gives an error.

EDIT: This is in fact, a c++ syntax question, not a Unix to Windows issue, as pointed out. The answer below works well.

Comment: C++ is the same language, nor depending on your operating system (not to mention Windows has had a POSIX subsystem for decades). So, why do you think you need to change this code at all? I'm a bit confused, because this really has nothing to do with Unix or windows. Please edit your question to clarify!

Comment: There are some differences though, are there not? The code which compiles fine on Unix, gives errors on Windows (visual studio 2015), for example, the first line above. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: There might be differences in compilers, but that's not a problem of the operating system. Since you weren't mentioning a change of compiler, I was assuming you used the same compiler, but for a windows instead of a Unix target. So, as much as I sometimes hate visualc++, in the 2015 version it's pretty OK. What is the c++ you were using before?

Comment: What is `_imageRows`? If it is not a compile time constant (which I doubt it is regarding its name), then your first line is not standard C++.

Comment: And, again, **edit** your question to include that info you just gave. Also include the error you were getting. This is an http://xyproblem.info

Comment: I have edited the question, and found the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @anti No, no, no... You clearly did not find the answer to your question, you find a way to make your code compile, it will crash at runtime obviously.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and patience! Much appreciated.

Comment: `float *[]` is **not** the same as `float *`. It should be `float **` and you should allocate memory for it differently if you want to use `[][]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
float *drowPtrs[_imageRows];
```

...is not allowed in standard C++ if `_imageRows` is not a compile-time constant. This likely compiles due to [GCC Variable-Length Arrays extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

This "declares" an array of pointer to `float` of size `_imageRows`.

The best solution would be to switch to vector:

```
std::vector<float*> drowPtrs(_imageRows);
```

Or better if you want a 2D array of float:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> drowPtrs(_imageRows);
```

---

An alternative solution is allocating this array dynamically:

```
float **drowPtrs = new float*[_imageRows];
```

...but you should put this into a `unique_ptr` to avoid having to manage the memory manually:

```
std::unique_ptr<float*[]> drowPtrs(new float*[_imageRows]);
```

---

...or if you really cannot, then you need to delete it manually when you are done:

```
delete[] drowPtrs;
```